# Dangers of Releasing the GIL in Cython?

Tags: python, cython, gil

If I choose to release the GIL in a Cython script what considerations do I have to make?

Are there any added dangers or risk to releasing the GIL in a Cython program?

Also how do I specify the number of threads to spawn?

Comment: Why do you ask? What's your use case? What does the extension module do?

Comment: I'm honestly curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I choose to release the GIL in a Cython script what considerations do I have to make?
>
> Are there any added dangers or risk to releasing the GIL in a Cython program?

You can't safely do anything that does anything interesting with a Python object. You can't safely do anything that touches your object's data without knowing that it's safe (possibly with your own lock).

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock will provide some information.

> Also how do I specify the number of threads to spawn?

Creating the threads is completely separately. You might do this with the `threading` module or you might do it any other way.

Comment: I see thanks for the insight. Seems best to limit releasing the GIL for strictly CPU bound problems with C types